# Why have error 'Internal Server Error' at create authorization request header in Hawk?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to encrypt my request data using [Hawk](https://github.com/hapijs/hawk#usage-example) on node.I use client code.

But when I create the request header,have an error:

```
{ Error: Invalid credentials
    at Object.exports.header (E:\work\spinarak\node_modules\@hapi\hawk\lib\client.js:69:15)
    at _push (E:\work\spinarak\Task\getResult.js:237:30)
    at _pushByApps (E:\work\spinarak\Task\getResult.js:222:4)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  data: null,
  isBoom: true,
  isServer: true,
  output:
   { statusCode: 500,
     payload:
      { statusCode: 500,
        error: 'Internal Server Error',
        message: 'An internal server error occurred' },
     headers: {} },
  reformat: [Function],
  typeof: [Function: Error] }
```

There is my code:

```
const Hawk = require('@hapi/hawk');
const Request = require('request');

async function _push(userinfo, content) {
    try {
        let credentials = {
            key: userinfo['secret'],
            algorithm: 'sha256',
            user: userinfo['id']
        }

        // The error at function that locates the following line
        let { header } = Hawk.client.header(userinfo['webhook'], 'POST', {
            credentials: credentials,
            payload: content
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

I have been looking online for a long time and have not found a solution. Why do I get an error when I create a request header? I have not officially sent a request yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh,I am very careless,I find error keyword at my code.

from:

```
let credentials = {
            key: userinfo['secret'],
            algorithm: 'sha256',
            user: userinfo['id']
        }
```

to:

```
let credentials = {
            key: userinfo['secret'],
            algorithm: 'sha256',
            id: userinfo['id']
        }
```

It can run.
This issue is not worth learning((